# Listing relationship properties in neo4j-shell

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to list the properties on a relationship within the neo4j-shell (version 2.0.0), but it isn't working:

```
neo4j-sh (3941248)$ ls -vr
(me)-[:HAS_SUBJECT,7509]->(2543867)
(me)-[:HAS_SUBJECT,7508]->(2867089)
(me)-[:HAS_SUBJECT,7507]->(3931268)
(me)-[:HAS_SUBJECT,7506]->(412527)
(me)-[:HAS_SUBJECT,7505]->(2152053)

neo4j-sh (3941248)$ cd -r 7505
neo4j-sh [:HAS_SUBJECT,7505]$ ls
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Node

neo4j-sh [:HAS_SUBJECT,7505]$ ls -p
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Node
neo4j-sh [:HAS_SUBJECT,7505]$ ls -r
(3941248) --[:HAS_SUBJECT,7505]-> (2152053)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I consider this a bug, please file a issue at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/new.
As a workaround you might use:

```
start r=relationship(7505) return r;
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan, that works fine for me. I'll file an issue right now.